# Animation of millimeter wave using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, physics

I'm trying to create a simulation of microwaves travelling and changing frequencies as they travel.
The x-axis is time, and the wave should move along the x-axis while subsequently changing frequencies (from 3GHz to 30GHz). The time interval is one nanosecond because higher than that they would be too fast to clearly notice the movement.

I have already created a static model of the wave matplotlib.pyplot. Now I want to use matplotlib.animation to animate it.
I could successfully create an animation of a sine wave by following the guide in this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/animations-with-matplotlib-d96375c5442c), but I don't know where to go from there.

How can I utilize the matplotlib.animation example code of drawing a sine wave and tweak it to be an animated microwave?

Model of the microwave:

[image]

Code used in plotting microwave model:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import chirp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')

T = 0.000000001 #one nanosecond 
n = 1000 # number of samples to generate - the more generated,the more smooth the curve
t = np.linspace(0, T, n, endpoint=False) # x-axis 
f0_micro = 3000000000 #frequency min value: 3GHz
f1_micro = 30000000000 #frequency max value: 30GHz
y_micro = chirp(t, f0_micro, T, f1_micro, method='logarithmic')

plt.plot(t,y_micro)
plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
plt.xlabel('t (secs)')
plt.title('Microwaves in one nanosecond')
plt.show()
```

Video of animated sine wave:

https://miro.medium.com/max/960/1*Aa4huCJefHt7nlX3nKQKGA.gif

Code used in plotting animated sine wave:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 4), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)


anim.save('sine_wave.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

Comment: first you would need function which can draw single static frame of animation depends on time.

Comment: In `animate(i)` it uses variable `i` (frame number) to generate different data for single frame. And your function has to do the same - for different `i` it has to draw different plot.

Comment: Can you provide a helpful code snippet? I don't know how to plot an animated version of a wave with varying frequency. @furas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of animation

[image]

Instead of drawing all points

```
plt.plot(t, y_micro) # <--- skip it
```

you have to create empty plot - with correct limits

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(t[0], t[-1]), ylim=(min(y_micro), max(y_micro)))

line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)
```

and later in `animation` you can use `i` to put only part of points

```
line.set_data(t[:i], y_micro[:i])
```

---

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import chirp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')

# --- generate all data without drawing ---

T = 0.000000001 #one nanosecond 
n = 1000 # number of samples to generate - the more generated,the more smooth the curve

t = np.linspace(0, T, n, endpoint=False) # x-axis 

f0_micro = 3000000000 #frequency min value: 3GHz
f1_micro = 30000000000 #frequency max value: 30GHz
y_micro = chirp(t, f0_micro, T, f1_micro, method='logarithmic')

# --- create empty plot ---

#plt.plot(t,y_micro) # <--- skip it

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(t[0], t[-1]), ylim=(min(y_micro), max(y_micro)))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)

# --- other elements on plot ---

plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
plt.xlabel('t (secs)')
plt.title('Microwaves in one nanosecond')

# --- animate it ----

def init():
    # put empty data at start
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,
    
def animate(i):
    # put new data in every frame using `i`
    line.set_data(t[:i], y_micro[:i])
    return line,

# calculate how many frames has animation
frames_number = len(t)

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=frames_number, interval=10, blit=True)

plt.show()

# I use `fps` (frames per second) to make it faster in file
anim.save('microwave.gif', fps=120) #, writer='imagemagick')
```

---

**EDIT**

If you need plot with margins then you have to add some values to limits because now plot doesn't add margins automatically.

```
x_margin = T/30  # I tested manually different values
y_margin = 0.1   # I tested manually different values

x_limits = (t[0] - x_margin, t[-1] + x_margin)
y_limits = (min(y_micro) - y_margin, max(y_micro) + y_margin)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=x_limits, ylim=y_limits)
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)
```

---

If you want faster animation in file then you may try to use `save( ..., fps= ...)` to chage number of `frames per second`.

Or you can draw less frames

```
frames_number = len(t) // 2
```

and display more points in every frame

```
i = i*2
line.set_data(t[:i], y_micro[:i])
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot, that worked :) I also appreciate your helpful notes about the margins and optimising the animation speed .. halving the frames helped a lot in decreasing the render time of the gif file.

Answer (score 2):

A newer and slightly more easier to use alternative to `matplotlib.animate` is celluloid.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import chirp
from celluloid import Camera

fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)

T = 0.000000001 #one nanosecond
n = 1000 # number of samples to generate - the more generated,the more smooth the curve
t = np.linspace(0, T, n, endpoint=False) # x-axis
f0_micro = 3000000000 #frequency min value: 3GHz
f1_micro = 30000000000 #frequency max value: 30GHz
y_micro = chirp(t, f0_micro, T, f1_micro, method='logarithmic')

for i in range(len(t)):

    plt.plot(t[:i], y_micro[:i], "r")
    camera.snap()

    plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
    plt.xlabel('t (secs)')
    plt.title('Microwaves in one nanosecond')

animation = camera.animate(interval=10)
plt.show()
```

It can do what you want to do with very little modifications to the code for a static plot. You don't need to define extra functions etc.

The final result looks like this [image: Pl]